# מָקוֹר - Why would we interpret 'maqor' as a "fountain"?

Tags: hebrew, word-study

The Hebrew term [maqor / מָקוֹר](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/4726.htm) (Heb. 4726) has 18 occurrences in the biblical text, and is traditionally rendered 'fountain' in most passages, from KJV (below) right through ESV and HCSB:

> Psalm 36:9 "For with thee [is] the **fountain** of life:"
>
> Proverbs 14:27 "...the LORD [is] a **fountain** of life,"
>
> Jeremiah 2:13 "they have forsaken me the **fountain** of living waters"

Considering the wider usage of the word (especially Lev 12:7, 20:18 which use it as a descriptor of a monthly period), it seems unlikely that 'fountain' in the modern English sense is the most typical implication of the term. Whilst it is possible this would be in the scope of the meaning, I'm wondering why the word would be rendered "fountain" anywhere at all, when 'spring' seems to cover all usages.

The LXX uses the phrase πηγὴν ὕδατος ζωῆς, which again suggests flowing, living water, but doesn't seem to explain why English favours a 'fountain'.

Is there good cause to preserve a 'fountain' translation of this term?

Comment: Is there much of a difference between “[fountain](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fountain)“ and “spring”?

Comment: In modern English I'd say there is a pronounced difference - with the ongoing demise of 'fountain pens' I'd suggest the term is used almost exclusively of elaborate jets of water, rather than a spring/source/reservoir.

Comment: @SteveTaylor The metaphorical use of "fountain" still works in my book. Regardless, I'd guess the translators are trying to preserve a distinction with עַ֫יִן (*ʿayin*) = "spring".

Comment: @Susan To my mind, the old "Fount" ties it with spring, but doesn't connote a park fountain with peeing statues :) I think it has more of a "source" meaning that just where the water comes out (the spring). But maybe my connotations are off.

Comment: It would be interesting to explore the difference between מָקוֹר and  מַעְיָן / עַיִן. I get the sense that one has to dig a מָקוֹר -- in Jer. 2 it's in parallel (or something) with בֹּארוֹת, and also apparently there's a verb קור = dig. I don't know enough about natural sources of running water. || I think Lev 12:7 is about the issuance of childbirth rather than menstruation. Same source, different physiology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary entry on “fountain”:

> 1. > a. **A spring** or source of water issuing from the earth and collecting in a basin, natural or artificial; also, the head-spring or source of a stream or river. **Now arch.** or poet. exc. fig.

Thus, the answer to your question is that the word “fountain” when the King James Version was produced in the 17th century was indeed synonymous with “spring.” That sense is now considered archaic.

Today, we commonly think of the following sense when we read or hear the word “fountain”:

> 2. > a. A jet or stream of water made to rise or spout up artificially; the structure built for such a jet or stream to rise and fall in; also, an erection in a public place for a constant supply of fresh water for drinking (more fully, drinking fountain). Applied also to a natural jet of water, as that of a geyser.

Steve Taylor, you are right. In modern English versions, it should be translated as “spring.”

---

#### References

“fountain, n.” *OED Online.* Oxford: Oxford UP, 2018. [www.oed.com/view/Entry/73957](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/73957). Accessed 5 December 2018.